# Need help reading Json file using C#

Tags: c#, json

I am using json file and trying to read using C#.

```
{
     "Company": {
               "ABC": {"ADDRESS" : "123 STREET",

            "DEF" :"ADDRESS 567",
            },


           },


     "Country": {

              "Country1": "XYZ",
              "Country2" : "ADG",

              }


 }
```

Here, I want to check ,if the  leaf node value is retrieved,then execute a condition i.e Company-> ABC -> Address -> "123"
So, 123 is leaf here.

Country -> Country1 -> "XYZ"

XYZ is leaf here .

```
string jsonFilePath = "D:\\ProjectCode1\\catalogJsonData.json";   
string json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);
Dictionary<string, object> json_Dictionary = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<Dictionary<string,    object>>(json);

 foreach (var item in json_Dictionary)
  {
   // parse here
      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Value);
      await context.PostAsync(item.Key);
  }
```

Above code i am not getting any value printed for item.Value or item.Key

Comment: Newtonsoft JSON

Comment: Are you using this form or parsing the file because it's the only way you know or is there another reason ?

Comment: That `json` isn't valid, it fails all RFC's; `trailing commas present`.

Comment: @Franck I have to do mapping in similar way ,but i am not sure about the syntax and RFC.  A node can have maximum nested level of 3 and minimum 1.

Comment: @MakeInIndiaInspire It's just that if you knew the format you just create a class with the proper properties and use that class as the deserialized object and it populate without problems. All that being said, Codexer brings up a good point as the `json` is not even valid. There are extra commas in couple places that make no sense. If that would be correct it be easy to parse using a class structure.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend creating a model class that your json can be deserialized to using the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet. I also cleaned your Json sample.

Json:

```
{
  "Company": {
    "ABC": {
      "ADDRESS": "123 STREET",
      "DEF": "ADDRESS 567"
    }
  },
  "Country": {
    "Country1": "XYZ",
    "Country2": "ADG"
  }
}
```

Code

```
class JsonModel
{
    public IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, string>> Company { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> Country { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("sample.json");
        var jsonModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(json);
        
        Console.WriteLine("-- Companies-- ");

        foreach(var companyDictionary in jsonModel.Company)
        {
            foreach(var company in companyDictionary.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{company.Key}:{company.Value}");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("-- Countries --");

        foreach (var country in jsonModel.Country)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{country.Key}:{country.Value}");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]